# Using Stripe Element createToken promise handler to submit form and click button

Tags: asp.net, webforms, stripe-payments

I'm looking at this JSFiddle code sample to use Stripe Element in a wizard like ASP.net webform application and after the payment page it needs to proceed to next page after Next is clicked.

Right now, I can get the token from serverside but the issue I'm having is that I couldn't find a way to click the Next button in the payment age. Because the initial form submit event was suppressed and the submit happens in the token promise handler which only submits the form but not click the Next button.

If I remove the e.preventDefault(); the form will be submitted regardless of the validity of the card info which is unwanted.

Any ideas?

Comment: the jsfiddle sample: https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/sxpjeocm/

Comment: you can always trigger button click event programmatically using javascript. e.g. http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ 
So one of the ideas is not triggering form submit at all, always using ajax to communicate with your backend; then trigger the button click using javascript in the server callback